# How should I put my funding history in CV/cover letter?

Tags: funding, faculty-application

I am applying for a faculty position after years of postdoc positions and a brief faculty position I held. My projects were rather unusual as I never received a big research fund. Instead, I received several smaller ones from different funding agencies. In total, the research funds I secured should be similar to those f my rivals.

My question is: Should I list the details of my funding history (in CV or cover letter) including the project title, the amount, and the funding agencies? Or it is enough to mention that I have received this amount of research fund in total from these funding agencies?

Comment: In a CV, yes. In cover letter, adding a line such as "Throughout my career, I was able to secure $XXX from various funding opportunities". Some might go into full details too!

Answer (score 1):

This will vary greatly by field so look at examples of CVs in your field. In general, it is very common to list the title, the start/end dates, the agency, the amount and your role in the grant on your CV. In some fields, it's also acceptable to list unawarded grants (we all know that obtaining funding can be a bit of a gamble - so many departments like to see that you're trying). I've never heard of funding being listed in the cover letter - but, again, that may be something specific to your field.